# Disable spring metric name rules for controllers and methods annotated with requestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, codahale-metrics

I'm new to Spring Boot Actuator and its metrics.

In documentation and all examples that I read it is always shown that spring exports endpoints metrics in such way `gauge.response.[method-path]`. But in some cases we have complex `@RequestMappings`. For example  have such mapping:

`@RequestMapping(value = {"{id:[^.]+}", "{id:[^.]+}.{type:\\w+}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

As a result spring will generate metrics with such ugly variables `gauge.response.500.{id:[^.]+}`, `gauge.response.200.{id:[^.]+}.{type:\\w+}"` (yeah I know that it will replace some symbols)

And in this case it would be much better if I could disable this and enable default naming like `gauge.response.[package.Class.method]` or something like that.

Comment: While this doesn't address customizing the metrics as you are asking, one approach is to bring in DropWizard as a dependency using the metrics for spring module here: http://metrics.ryantenney.com/. Then you can simply add a Timed annotation and set the value to a more descriptive name. These metrics will then be available in your spring boot metrics endpoint. If this answers your question, let me know and I'll move this to the answer.